# Calculating the mean by name of a named numeric returing another named numeric as a result

Tags: r

I am working on a code which has a for loop. At the end of each iteration, a named numeric vector is concatenated to the one of the previous loop.

```
all_obj <- c()
for (i in 1:3){
  obj <- 1:3*i
  names(obj) <- c('foo', 'baz', 'bar')
  all_obj <- c(all_obj, obj)
}
```

At the end, `all_obj` looks like this:

```
foo baz bar foo baz bar foo baz bar 
  1   2   3   2   4   6   3   6   9
```

What I would need now is to have a result which is the mean by name of this vector, and it is a named numeric itself.

**Expected result**

```
foo baz bar
  2   4   6
```

I know I can get the values with name `foo` (for example) with `all_obj[names(all_obj) == "foo"]`. But I am bit stuck as to how would I reach my desired result from here without having to convert the data too much (e.g. avoiding doing `as.data.frame` for instance). Not that there is anything wrong with this, it's just a matter of preference and curiosity.

This was my best attempt so far.

```
lapply(unique(names(all_obj)), function(x) mean(all_obj[names(all_obj) == x]))
#[[1]]
#[1] 2
#
#[[2]]
#[1] 4
#
#[[3]]
#[1] 6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tapply` is well suited for that task:

```r
tapply(all_obj, names(all_obj), mean)

# bar baz foo 
#   6   4   2
```

Comment: Haha I've just edited my answer to include `tapply`, since you've included your answer here, I'll re-edit my answer to remove it :)

Answer (score 1):

An other way in base R is to split `all_obj` according to `names`, and calculate mean for each group using `sapply`.

```
sapply(split(all_obj, names(all_obj)), mean)
bar baz foo 
  6   4   2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this was very easy....

I am posting the solution here so that it hopefully help anyone with my same requirement.

```
sapply(unique(names(all_obj)), function(x) mean(all_obj[names(all_obj) == x]))
```

**Result**

```
foo baz bar 
  2   4   6
```